# How to use `read` function from unistd.h after a `timer_create` function in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, timer, arguments

It is possible to use `read()`[from `unistd.h`] function after `timerfd_create()` and `timerfd_settime()`. The filedescriptor returned by `timerfd_create` can be used as arg1 to `read`. If I use `timer_create` to create the timer, what should be arg1 of `read` funtion?

I am coding in C++.

Comment: I don't think `read` and `timer_create` mix.

Comment: You can't use `read` with a timer created with `timer_create`. I can't think of anything that would suggest that you could.